# How to create a block response like Alamofire Responses?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, completionhandler

May this question be dumb, but I was looking a way to create optional responses like Alamofire 4.0 have (eg. responseJSON,responseData, responseString etc). For example, in my project I have BaseService which make the request (using alamofire) then handle the response (for erros, if has, it calls a exception class which shows a message an break the flow). So, I have subclasses that inherit from my BaseService, and my methods has completions blocks who parse and pass any data (or error if need) from BaseService.

Theen, my question is: my BaseService request function may return (as block) a response, json or an error, ex: completionHandler(response,json, error) or  completionHandler(nil, json, nil)

So when I don't need a response or json, just want verify if error isn't nil I've to do like this:

myFunc() { ( _ *,* _,error) in }

How do I do to get only the block that I want? Like Alamofire do with his response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide your completionHandler at you `BaseService` class to each service function to `onSuccess` and `onFail` ... etc

Example:

```
    func logInUser( _ userEmail : String, userPassword : String, onSuccess: @escaping (Any?)-> Void, onFail : @escaping (Error?) ->(Void))  {

    let url : URLConvertible = urls.loginUser

    let parameters = ["email" : userEmail, "password" : userPassword]

    let header = ["Authorization" : APPSECRETKEY ]

    alamofireManager.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

        if response.result.value != nil && response.result.error == nil {

        onSuccess(response.result.value)

        }
        else
        {
          onFail(response.result.error)

        }
    })

}
```

When you call your service function:

```
    BaseService.sharedInstance.logInUser("email", userPassword: "password",

                            onSuccess: { responseValue in



                            },

                            onFail: { error in





                            })
```

Comment: Hi @Ayman there is a way to make this blocks optionals directly on the function declaration? So then I can call 'onSuccess' or 'onFail' only if needed?